# Easter Egg Badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, easter-eggs

Are there any unlisted badges?

I almost envisioned easter egg badges on embarassing activity: Like "First time you tried to upvote your own question" or "First question that recieved more upvotes from comments than from the question"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the [Hacker Badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/) which has never been awarded.

In the linked blog post, Jeff also says

> (There might even be some other secret badges out there.. who knows?)

but if there are others they've remained secret.