# Are there any secret badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

**Note: Don't list them if there are, I just want to know if they exist.**

I have noticed that there are several posts on meta asking for secret badges. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213132/290073) answer suggests they are being considered, but have they been implemented?

Comment: If it's secret, why should we tell?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm asking if aliens exist, not where they are.

Comment: lol, answer is the same: official answer will always be "no", but in reality, they might just exist.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This question should probably be directed towards Jon Skeet, since he has all the badges, whether they exist or not.

Comment: Actually he might have the most amount of badges, but most of them are for answers - I'm sure others got way more distinct badges than him. :)

Comment: I have several secret badges.  The problem is that if they are displayed in your badge count, then they are no longer secret.  So only the users who have them can see them.  [Here's an example from my account](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xWjXS.png)

Comment: @Won't, dammit, you just earned another secret badge for revealing your secret badge, didn't you?

Comment: Related: [Easter egg badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108118)

Comment: [There is a secret badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122625/349538), but it has never been awarded.

Answer (score 2):

Since [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213130/21960) hasn't been implemented, and presumably they're still "thinking about it", I'd say the answer is **no**.

Further, I'd expect if there were, someone would have already been trumpeting about achieving it.

Since we've not seen that, I would take that as strong evidence of a lack. (If the badge is a secret and no one can get it, does it really exist?)

Comment: true, and we might have official response in 6-8 years.